# Winginx 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: winginx

I have downloaded and installed winginx server on my windows platform and everything is working fine accept when I try to import a database dump using phpadmin I get this error message:

"504 Gateway Time-out"

Does somebody know how to fix this when using winginx?

Answer (score 0):

This is a wrong configured nginx server. Try to replace `localhost:xxxx` with `127.0.0.1:xxxx` in all configuration files.
Some of them are located in Winginx\conf such as:

- tools-adminer.conf
- tools-phpmemcachedadmin.conf
- tools-phpmyadmin.conf
- tools-rockmongo.conf

The other configuration is accessible through the workbench.

Answer (score 0):

Having just experienced this I guess you didn't select to install PHP 5.3 (who needs that now).

The line that you need to update in each of these files is

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9054;
```

The 9054 is the port userd for PHP 5.4